# Subversion rename problem

Tags: svn

I'm working in a small company, and my task is actually doing a kind of monkey testing. However sometimes programming also belongs to my job. As a result, I have to repeatedly review the merging and reintegrating procedure after a period interval. Sorry for such a kind of useless complaint.

To my problem:
For our SW development we use subversion for version control. I have set up a branch naming A, and its working copy is also available. Later i found the name `A` didn't sound explicit, and renamed the branch `A` in the server to `AB`. When i try to merge the changes in the `trunk` to my working copy, i get an error saying A not found. How could i get around this issue? Should i use `Relocate`?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `svn switch AB` on the working copy first.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. Do you mean switching the working copy to AB in the server? Is Relocate necessary after Switch?

Comment: You only need to use the svn switch --relocate command if you move the repository to another server with a different URL or IP address.